# How to Check device Dicovery and undiscovery of Bluetooth Le Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am Working on Android application that List out the Bluetooth LE device which are discovered.

I am using following code to Scan BLE Devices.

```
    BluetoothManager mBta = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
    SNFBluetoothAdapter mSNFBluetoothAdapter=new SNFBluetoothAdapter(MainActivity.this);

    mBta.startLeScan(mSNFBluetoothAdapter);
```

Using This method I am able to Scan the Bluetooth Devices in Range in.

```
    onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
```

But Now My Issue is, 
How can I check that Device Goes Out of bluetooth range and update my List of Devices? 
Please Help.

Sorry for my Language.

Comment: You can see if something previously found does not get found again in some reasonable number of attempts. A decreasing rssi could also be a clue. Likely you will need to tune the decisioning to your application needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the Timer to Refresh the List.

After Some Specific time Reset the List Data and ReFetch the DeviceList so it will fetch new List which are  In Range Devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use several developers sdk. Check out for Radius Network beacon and Estimote beacon. Estimote descovers only estimote beacons. Beacons have proximity functions as your requirements and they can notify you when you enter / exit in the area.

Comment: The question is not specific to "beacons" and additionally SO prefers answers which provide a stand alone explanation and do not merely point to another place.

Answer (score 0):

The method `onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)` always run unless you stop this process.

So, if `Device Goes Out of bluetooth range`, it will automatically disappear.

No need worry.

Comment: @ Alex Tran.
I am managing ArrayList of Devices and Displaying it in ListView.
And onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) Only Calls when Device come in the bluetooth range. So in onLeScan method I am adding Device to my List. 
So If Device goes Out of range I have to remove the device from my List , So using this method it is not possible. 
Try the code and If possible then Please Describe.